# difference between cache & local pages

Tags: android, webview, android-tablayout

My application consists of tablayout with webview in each tab. There are two ways of loading offline content one is loading local pages & the other is caching. I am currently using caching , however which is faster ? Is loading local pages obsolete or redundant ? 
For example when the webpage loading is complete I want to save it in 
when I swipe from one tab to the other , no matter what I do the webpage will reload. I just want it to be blistering click just like viewing photos in a photo gallery.I tried almost everything and finally want to check loading local pages i.e when the user will navigate to different pages a local page will load.

Will it make any difference ?